# How to make HTTP request from Okhttp Authenticator?

Tags: okhttp

I'm using Okhttp3 and I want to build an OAuth2 `Authenticator`.

Sometimes, I need to make http requests from the Authenticator itself (ie: to refresh the token) but the api doesn't provide a way to do it.

For sure, I can create a new okhttp instance but I don't know if it is a recommanded practice.

Is it a best practice for my need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do it out of the box but some workarounds can work:

- create a new instance of `OkHttpClient` into the `Authenticator`, or
- add a setHttpClient method in Authenticator

.

```
MyAuthenticator authenticator = new MyAuthenticator();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .authenticator(authenticator)
    .build();
authenticator.setHttpClient(client);
```

From: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2733